# How do I revert the MUST_CHANGE in this SQL Statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I executed

```
SELECT N'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + N' WITH PASSWORD = N'''' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_POLICY = ON;' 
  FROM sys.sql_logins 
  --WHERE is_policy_checked = 0;
```

But I don't want the `MUST_CHANGE`option on the login.

Did this query actually change anything or is this just a simple select?

Comment: "Consider revising your question so that it appeals to a broader audience. " - it would be great if someone is willing to revert the question to my last edit, thus it will make sense for the the broader audience.  The way it is now, it is quite useless indeed.

Comment: The problem with your last edit was that it changed the question completely. The fact that this question is closed doesn't prevent you from asking the latest revision as a new question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That query didn't change anything so you don't need to revert anything.

That is just a simple select generating an `ALTER LOGIN`statement.

If you didn't execute the resulting statement nothing has been changed.